# Button to increment a number on screen

Tags: javascript, html

I want, per button click, to increase the variable `hey`.
However, it doesn't increase.

What's going wrong?

```js
var hey = 0

function hi() {
  hey = ++hey
}

document.write(window.hey)
```

```html
<button onclick="hi()">HI</button>
```

Comment: You need to somehow update the printed value

Comment: Hmm, indeed... very strange...

Comment: *"However, it just doesn't increase. Strange, isn't it?"* - Not really, if you don't tell it do something it's not going to do it for you. The variable `hey` is updated on click, but you never said to write it or put it on the DOM. (*Note: you don't want to do `document.write` inside your method, it would clear the entire DOM, instead manipulate and update a DOM element*)

Comment: `window.hey`? You sure?

Comment: the process of reaching 'somehow' is the question...

Comment: @Clint hey is set as the `onclick` attribute of the button

Comment: @James_Parsons Thanks, I realized my error pretty quick, not as quick as you though!

Comment: could someone modify my codes if it is possible. I consider a visual image to be most helpful.

Comment: Also, I'm just gonna warn OP, when you get it working, `document.write()` will not give you desired behavior

Comment: I know that the <span></span> thingy would help. But in the actual game, I'm not trying to display the value of the variable - such as 1 or 2 or 3. Im trying to increase the variable so I can form a equation in the <script></script> section.

Comment: @EricLi All you need to do is make an HTML element like `<div id="count">0</div>`. Then you can reference that element and store the value of `hey` as it's text.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek how should I do that? Is it really hard?

Comment: @EricLi If you don't need to display it then your code works fine, `hey` is updated on each click as I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek Im trying the change the value of the variable "hey" globally. Don't know how to do that........

Comment: @EricLi As I said you are doing that already.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek locally it is increasing, but not globally

Comment: @EricLi There is no local `hey`, only the global one. It would only be local if you created a local one `var hey = ...` inside your function, since your not it updates the global one. You can test this yourself by adding another event listener and making it do something like `console.log(hey)` or `alert(hey)` will show you that it did indeed update. Or you can check it directly in the console.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, but there were a few issues with your code.

**Side Note**: In programming, it's pretty much always a good idea to name your variables/functions something meaningful and descriptive.

In the code sample below, I changed the name of your function `hey` to `increment` since the purpose of that function is to increment the value of our variable (which I also renamed `i`).

I also replaced your `document.write()` with a `console.log()`

```js
//create a global variable called i
var i = 0

//increment i each time the function is called
function increment() {
  i = ++i;
  console.log(i);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button onclick="increment()">Increment</button>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I have added some more details, would you mind taking a look at them,?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you only output the value once upon load.
You'll need to update the display every time the button is clicked, from within the function.

I recommend not using `document.write`, but updating a specific DOM element instead.

I also recommend binding an event listener, rather than using an inline handler;
though [either method will work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers).

```js
var hey = 0;
var trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');
var display = document.getElementById('display');

function increment() {
  display.innerText = ++hey;
}

trigger.addEventListener('click',increment);
```

```html
<button type="button" id="trigger">INCREMENT</button>
<span id="display">0</span>
```

Comment: Hi, I have added some more details, would you mind taking a look at them?

Comment: Your edit introduces a different question altogether. I recommend rolling it back or deleting this question and creating a new post.

Comment: Now I have to wait six days.  Awesome

Comment: Ah, that sucks.